# Having trouble reading the .src of an image in the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, src

I'm attempting an Othello game in which the user clicks on a square to place the token.  I've created the board in a table, and here is a typical line:

```
<td class="cell" id="2-1" onclick="placeToken(this.id)"> <img src="/images/emptySquare.png"></td>
```

My JavaScript can console.log the id properly, but when I click on the square and try to console.log the .src, I get undefined.  Here's the line in JS:

```
console.log(document.getElementById(id).src);
```

Comment: The td doesn't have a src property, the img does

Comment: And it's that simple... THANKS!